# How to show inserted/affected rows after query with phpmyadmin (4.2.3)?

Tags: phpmyadmin

PMA (4.2.2 + 4.2.3) behaves different showing affected/inserted/deleted rows after insert/update/delete query. If I am using the "Insert"-tab, inserted rows are shown. If I use the "SQL"-tab, always "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)." is shown.
In PMA (3.4.11 Debian) affected/inserted/deleted rows are always shown.

Example A:

*Server: Servername -> Database: test1 -> Table: fruits -> "Insert"* an apple
produces a query like:

```
INSERT INTO `test1`.`fruits` (`id`, `fruit`) VALUES (NULL, 'apple');
```

The response on the next window: 
**1 row inserted. Inserted row id: 1**

Example B:

*Server: Servername -> Database: test1 -> Table: fruits -> "SQL"* 
inserting a banana:

```
INSERT INTO `test1`.`fruits` (`id`, `fruit`) VALUES (NULL, 'banana');
```

The reponse on the next window:
**MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0017 seconds.)**

I got my banana in the table, but for processing more complex queries it is not very convenient. Is this a bug in newer versions of phpmyadmin? What can I do to display the status of the affected/inserted/deleted rows like in earlier versions?

Comment: This is a bug in phpMyAdmin 4.2 and I have submitted the bug ticket [Bug #4457](https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/4457/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a confirmed bug in phpMyAdmin 4.2.3 (see [Bug #4457](https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/4457/)). This is now fixed in v4.2.4 (yet to be released) using this [patch](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/commit/4c4cee598a4c4a332424340ce1833213f70ea2ff.patch) which I had proposed to them.

Comment: Thank you for the help. After applying the patch to 4.2.3 the affected rows are shown as expected.